# Окончание в слове «участников»

Tags: грамматика

"Деятельность субъектов, рассматриваемых нами как участников/ки процесса взаимодействия" — подскажите, какое окончание должно быть в слове «участников»?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, лучше так: *деятельность субъектов, рассматриваемых нами в качестве участников процесса взаимодействия*.

Answer (score 0):

Грамматически правильно "рассматриваемых как участники".
"Рассматиривать как участников", но "рассматриваемые как участники" - во всех падежах, причастие накладывает свои правила согласования.  
А лучше всего заменить "как" на "в качестве участников". Тогда сомнений не будет.

Я не видел предыдущего ответа. Это просто общее мнение.